# mitmproxy installed with pip, get error

Tags: macos, pip, mitmproxy

I installed the `mitmproxy` on Mac OS `10.11` with `pip`. But I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy", line 7, in <module>
    from mitmproxy.main import mitmproxy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mitmproxy/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import _thread  # PY3: We only need _thread.error, which is an alias of RuntimeError in 3.3+
ImportError: cannot import name _thread
```

Comment: If you've got homebrew, you could install it with `brew install mitmproxy` instead of messing with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two versions of six installed, and one of them is outdated. If you remove the outdated one, mitmproxy should find the new one and work.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install mitmproxy` works fine.